# Absolute Value of A Real VS. Complex Number

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

I am came across a problem that asked me to find the magnitude of a complex number:

$$|4 + 3i|$$

After reading online and the textbook, I figured out the question could be solved by finding the distance of the complex number from the origin on a complex plane. As so:

[image]

I understand this so far. However, my trouble is that when I solve, using the Pythagorean theorem:

$\begin{align}\sqrt{4^{2} + (3i)^{2}} &= \sqrt{16 + 9i^{2}} \\
&= \sqrt{16 - 9} \\
&= \sqrt{7}
\end{align}$

I end up getting the incorrect solution (the correct solution is 5). Now, when I plug $|4 + 3i|$ into my TI-84, I get 5 as a result. I did some research into the magnitudes of absolute values and saw that they can be found by taking the square root of the product of the complex conjugate pair. Solving it this way, I also got 5 as a solution. I am confused as to why the absolute value of a complex number is treated so differently to that of a real number. Why is this and what is the correct way to solve for the magnitude of a complex number?

Edit:

Thanks for all the responses. I'm still having trouble understanding how you can ignore the $i$ when looking at the distance from $0$ to $3i$. I attempted to draw a diagram to better understand this:

[image]

I'm rather confused as to why the distance between $0$ and $3$ is $3$, but the distance between $0$ and $3i$ is also $3$. Wouldn't this imply that $|3|$ and $|3i|$ are equal? If so, how is that possible?

Comment: The lengths of the sides are simply $4$ and $3$. There is no $i$ in Pythagora's.

Comment: The modulus of $4 + 3 i$ is the distance in the plane between the points $(0,0)$ and $(4, 3)$.

Comment: `why the absolute value of a complex number is treated so differently than a real number` On the contrary, they are treated exactly the same. You can write any real number $a$ as $a + 0 \cdot i$ and calculate its absolute value as $\sqrt{a^2+0^2}=\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$.

Comment: Draw the picture for |-3| with the points being -3,-2,-1.  The distance is 3 not negative 3.  If someone asked you how -3 became positive and how can |-3| = 3, what would you answer.  ... and yes  |3i| = |3| = |-3| = |-3i|.  Because absolute values are always positive.  i is *not* positive.  It isn't negative.  It is a new direction.

Comment: Notice this $3 = 3 + 0i$ so $|3|^2 = (3 + 0i)(3- 0i) = 3^2 + 0^2 = 9$ so $|3| = 9$.  $|-3|^2 = (-3 + 0i)(-3 - 0i) = (-3)^2 + 0^2 = 9$.  And $3i = 0 + 3i$ so $|3i|^2 = (0 + 3i)(0 - 3i) = 0^2 -(0*3 - 0*3)i - 3^2i^2 = 0 - 0i -(-9) = 9$.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for all the help. That last comment just did it for me. I'm now picturing a graph with two axis (directions of + real, - real, + imaginary, and - imaginary) and a circle of radius 3, centered at the origin. The circle encompasses 3, -3, 3i, and -3i because they're all the same distance, just in different directions.

Comment: Exactly!  The circle also includes $0.93969262078590838405410927732473 +0.34202014332566873304409961468226 i$ and  an infinitude of other combinations.  All of them a distance of 3 from the origin.

Comment: Oops, the numbers on that least one don't work.  The idea was to pick random $x,y$ so that $x^2 + y^2 = 3$ and so $|x + yi| = 3$ but... I made an error and forgot to multiply by 3.  Instead $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.  [ I plugged cos/sin 20 into a calculator... which could give you some food for thought.  a + bi exresses a complex number in rectangular coordinates... do you think there is a way to express them in circular coordinates?  Well, maybe later...]

Comment: Isn't cos(20)/sin(20) the same as tan(20)?

Comment: Added in as new comment b/c edit time ran out: I get the point you were trying to demonstrate and how one would calculate the points, but I'm not clear on " [ I plugged cos/sin 20 into a calculator." Also, if by circular coordinates you mean polar coordinates (excuse me if I am wrong here, I'm still in PreCalc, so I'm not 100% sure about what I am doing), wouldn't the polar coordinates be (3, every angle). I've only seen polar coordinates used for a single point in the form (distance to origin, angle from origin). If you wanted to represent a circle, wouldn't that be every angle from 0-360?

Comment: A different way to look at this is that the abs value of a real number $a$ is $\sqrt{(a^2)}$. If you accept that the abs value of a complex number should be a non-negative real number, you can't use the same definition for the abs value of $z=x+iy$, because $(x+iy)^2 = x^2-y^2+2ixy$ is usually complex, not real. A definition that "works" is to multiply $z$ by its complex conjugate $\bar z = x - iy$, i.e. $|z| = \sqrt{z\bar z} = \sqrt{(x + iy)(x - iy)} = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. If you go on to study math at university level, you will find why this definition isn't just "pulled out of the air".

Comment: @EricWiener tan(20) = sin(20)/cos(20), not cos(20)/sin(20).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, oh my, you've done it almost right!  It is actually given as

$$|4+3i|=\sqrt{4^2+3^2}=\sqrt{25}=5$$

In general,

$$|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

This is because the absolute value only considers $a$ and $b$ as the length of each side of the triangle.  Length can't, by definition, be a complex number.

This is like considering the absolute value of a negative number:

$$|-1|=1$$

The absolute value doesn't care which side of $0$ you are at, just how far.  So the same goes for complex numbers, and we end up having

$$|3i|=3$$

Now, $|3i|=|3|$ does not mean that $3i=3$, for the reason that it is simply on a different side of $0$.  This kind of logic would say $1=-1$, since their absolute values are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! However, I'm still a little confused. The vertical component 3i. How are you able to just use 3 and drop the i?

Comment: The vertical length is not 3i, the vertical length is 3.

Comment: @EricWiener Well, you've defined absolute value as "the distance from $0$", right?  And the distance, has nothing to do with complex numbers.  It only measures how **far** from one spot to the next.

Comment: Wouldn't the distance between 0 and 3i be 3i?

Comment: @EricWiener Well, its not the distance from $0$ to $3i$ actually.  It's asking you to take a ruler from point a to point b, essentially, distance.

Comment: @EricWiener Intuitively, what is $|3i|$?  Draw that, and use a "ruler" to solve.  Do you think that would help?

Comment: I attempted to draw a diagram (edited my post to include it). I'm still quite baffled at why 3i can be considered only 3 away from 0. If you were to swap i out for x, having the number be 3x, the number would be 3x away from 0, not just 3 away. What is different about the complex number system that allows this?

Comment: @EricWiener How about this algebraic approach:$$|x^2|=|x|^2\implies |i^2|=|i|^2$$

Comment: @EricWiener Oh, better yet:$$|-1|=1\ne-1$$Does this make sense why one would have $|i|=1$?

Comment: That did the trick. I never thought of it as: |i| -> |(-1)^-2| -> |(-1)|^-2 -> |1|^2 -> 1. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @EricWiener :D Your welcome! *tips the hat*

Comment: " If you were to swap i out for x, the number would be 3x away from 0, not just 3 away."  Not if x is negative.  If x = -1 then 3x = -3 and that is 3 away. Think of it this way.  The origin (0,0) has four distinct rays extending from it in four directions.  One extends in the "positive real" direction.  Every number in it is some $x*1$ for some $x$.  The other is "negative real" every number is some $x*(-1)$.  The third is the "positive imaginary" every number is some $x*i$.  The fourth is "negative imaginary" every number is some $x*(-i)$.  Each has magnitude $x$

Comment: (+1)(-1)(+i)(-i) are unitary directions.  Just as "-3" means "$3*(-1)$" means "three in the negative direction", the $3i$ means "$3*i$" means "three in the imaginary direction".  Distance (or magnitude) are always positive (non-negative) real values no matter what direction they are in.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, that is correct.  I tried to point out such topics in my answer as well.

Comment: I hope the OP sits and thinks about it and it eventually comes to him/her.  The question was clearly asked and the OP is clearly intelligent.

Comment: @fleablood yes, it does seem that way.

Comment: I recommend you look at fleablood's comments, as they also explain some of what is happening here.  @EricWiener

Comment: Trying to wrap my head around them right now. Thanks.

Comment: @EricWiener if I may insert a side comment, understanding there is a relationship between $a+bi$ and it's absolute value **and** direction are good places to start learning about DeMoivre's formula and Euler's formula for complex numbers, which come in handy.

Answer (score 15):

The *definition* (or one possible definition) of the absolute value of the complex number $a+bi$ (where $a$ and $b$ are real) is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.  So you ask, why is it not $\sqrt{a^2+(bi)^2}$ instead?  The answer is that this is simply how we choose to define it.  You could define a different quantity which is $\sqrt{a^2+(bi)^2}$, but you would have to give a different name to it because everyone else has already agreed that "absolute value" means to take $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ instead.

Now, a more interesting question is *why* everyone else decided on that definition.  One reason is that you can represent complex numbers as points in the plane by letting $a+bi$ correspond to the point $(a,b)$, and then $|a+bi|$ is the distance from this point to the origin.  Note that when you do this, $(a,b)$ is just a point in the ordinary Euclidean plane: it is a point that is $a$ units to the right of the origin and $b$ units above the origin.  It doesn't make sense to say that the vertical distance is $bi$, since in geometry when we measure distances they are always positive real numbers.  The vertical distance is $b$ because you have moved $b$ units vertically in the plane.  (Actually, this is only accurate if $b$ is positive: if $b$ is negative, you have moved $-b$ units down, and so the distance is $-b$ rather than $b$.  But you end up squaring this quantity when you use the Pythagorean theorem, so it doesn't matter if it's negative.)

Now ultimately this explanation is not very satisfying, because it doesn't explain why we chose to represent complex numbers in the plane this way.  For instance, why don't we choose to represent them such that the complex number $i$ corresponds to a vertical distance different from $1$, or a distance in some direction other than vertical?  One answer is that choosing $i$ to mean "go up one unit" happens to make distance have nice algebraic properties we would like absolute values to have.  For instance, for real numbers, it is true that $|xy|=|x||y|$.  Defining absolute values of complex numbers by $|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, it turns out that this is true for complex numbers as well.  As a simple example, if we want $|xy|=|x||y|$ to be true for complex numbers, then we should have $|i|^2=|i^2|=|{-1}|=1$.  So we should define $|i|=1$ or $-1$, and it is sensible to define it to be $1$ instead of $-1$ since absolute values are supposed to be positive.

Comment: So really, the definition of a complex number's absolute value has been somewhat arbitrarily decided on?

Comment: @RandomUser: Sure, you could say that.  The same is true for every other definition in mathematics.

Comment: Thanks, because it was hard for me to wrap my mind around the notion that this is "objectively" how the absolute value of a complex number is supposed to look like.. in reality it was just my mistaken assumption, and it is nothing more than a mathematical convention.

Answer (score 2):

You ask:

> Wouldn't the distance from $0$ to $3i$ be $3i$, not $3$?

No, not quite, for the same reason that the distance from $3$ to $0$ is not $-3$. Distance is not simply the difference, but the *absolute value* of the difference.

Of course, you'll probably find this unhelpful and circular. There are a few different ways you can think about $|z|$:

- Length of the line from $0$ to $z$ (note that lengths are always positive, no matter if along the positive reals, negative reals, or any other direction of the complex plane)
- $\sqrt{z\bar z}$ (multiplying by the complex conjugate $\bar z$ takes any number to the positive reals - it's equivalent to the $\sqrt {x^2}$ formula from the real numbers)
- the radius $r$ when the number is expressed as $r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$, also known as polar form
- the nonnegative real number you "land on" if you rotate the plane around the origin so your point ends up on the nonnegative part of the real axis

But all of these are restricted to being positive.

---

If complex absolute value was defined as $\sqrt{a^2 + (bi)^2}$, then starting at $z=3$ and "moving" upwards along the positive imaginary direction would *decrease* the absolute value. If we want absolute value to measure "distance from $0$" in some sense, then moving farther away from $0$ would make $\sqrt{a^2 + (bi)^2}$ a smaller number! We want our absolute value to *increase* when we move away from $0$, not decrease.

We want our definition of "absolute value" to not change if we rotate the plane around the origin, and we want the absolute value of a nonnegative real number to equal itself. These make our *only option* for the definition of $|z|$ to be $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with a space of numbers, such as a one-dimensional real line $\mathbb{R}$, a two dimensional real space $\mathbb{R}^2$, or the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, we often need a sort of measure to compare the individual elements. This measuring apparatus is called a [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)). So far, you've been exposed to the Absolute Value and Euclidean Norms. The whole purpose of a norm is to assign a positive value to each non-zero number in the space (vectors, really, but let's not be picky) and the value of zero to, well, the zero element.

For real numbers on the one-dimensional number line $\mathbb{R}$, it is sensible to assign the size as the absolute value, $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$, which gives us the distance of a number from zero.

[image: real line]

In a two-dimensional real space, such a plane where we have ordered pairs $(x,y)$ assigned to every point, an intuitive norm that coincides with our physical sense of distance is given by the Pythagorean theorem.
$$||(x,y)|| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
This is the Euclidean norm. It is *not* the only norm we could equip $\mathbb{R}^2$ with, but it is the most frequently used one. Coincidentally, this Euclidean norm extends for usage on any $n$-dimensional real space,
$$||(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)|| = \sqrt{x^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_n^2}$$
and, loosely speaking, gives the distance of the number from the origin.

[image: real2]

For complex numbers, we also want to create a norm. Again, we want some apparatus to compare the sizes of numbers. *By definition*, we want this to be a mathematical device that takes in any non-zero complex number $z=x+iy$ and returns a positive real number. The Pythagorean formula almost provides this, but as you saw, it would return a complex number. That's no good. Our solution is to purposefully define the Euclidean norm for a complex plane as

$$|z| = |x+iy| = \sqrt{(x+iy)(x-iy)} = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$

Note that we take in a complex number, but return a non-negative, real one. That's critical. There is no notion of order for complex numbers (is $i$ greater than $1$, less than, or equal to?), yet by returning a real number, we now are able to compare sizes.

Note, now, how similar it is to compare the magnitudes of numbers on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

[image: complex]

Answer (score 0):

$$|z|^2=z\bar z\implies |4+3i|^2=(4+3i)(4-3i)=16+9=25\implies |4+3i|=5.$$

Comment: I think that'll require more explanation to the OP.

Comment: Why can (4+3i)^2 be represented at (4+3i)(4-3i)?

Comment: In my opinion this avoids the issue and heart of the OP's question if absolute value means distance from origin how do you calculate it.  If we simply say "absolute value means something that looks entirely different and which has nothing apparently to do with distances at all" we aren't really explaining anything.  Of course $\sqrt{z\overline z}$ has *everything* to do with distance.  But it's far from apparent.

Comment: @EricWiener $(4+3i)^2 = (4+3i)(4+3i)$. However $|4+3i|^2 = (4+3i)(4-3i)$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct when you say that

$\vert \vert x\vert \vert ^2 =x \bar x $,

where $\vert \vert x\vert \vert ^2$ is the magnitude squared and $\bar x $ is the complex conjugate.

It is not too hard to show that if $x=a+bi$,

$\vert \vert x\vert \vert ^2 = a^2 + b^2$.

The only error in your calculation and in your picture is the inclusion of $i$ in your altitude of the right triangle, which caused a -9 as opposed to 9.

Note that the absolute value of a real number is just that number's distance to the origin (we take 0 to be the origin for a real number).  The complex version of the absolute value, the magnitude, actually tries to do the same thing$-$it gives the distance from a complex number to the origin.

Comment: `the absolute value of a real number is just that number's distance to the origin (which is 0 for a real number)` It's not $0$, you must have meant something else.

Comment: @dxiv Andy is referring to the origin as $0$, but the wording makes it seem like he's referring the the *distance* as $0$.

Comment: @zahbaz Quite possibly, but the origin is one and the same for all numbers in the complex plane, so the bolded part in "*distance to the origin (which is 0* ***for a real*** *number)*" makes it even more confusing. I wish Andy clarified the wording.